# Can somebody shed a light what this strange DHT response means?

Tags: bittorrent, dht, kademlia

Sometimes I receive this strange responses from other nodes. Transaction id match to my request transaction id as well as the remote IP so I tend to believe that node responded with this but it looks like sort of a mix of response and request

```
d1:q9:find_node1:rd2:id20:.éV0özý.?tj­N.?.!2:ip4:DÄ.^7:nodes.v26:.ï?M.:iSµLW.ÐÃ¤¸úzDÄ.^æCe1:t2:..1:y1:re
```

Worst of all is that it is malformed. Look at 7:nodes.v it means that I add nodes.v to the dictionary. It is supposed to be 5:nodes. So, I'm lost. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internet and remote nodes is unreliable or buggy. You have to code defensively. Do not assume that everything you receive will be valid.

Remote peers might

- send invalid bencoding, discard those, don't even try to recover.
- send truncated messages. usually not recoverable unless it happens to be the very last `e` of the root dictionary.
- omit mandatory keys. you can either ignore those messages or return an error message
- contain corrupted data
- include unknown keys beyond the mandatory ones. this is not an error, just treat them as if they weren't there for the sake of forward-compatibility
- actually be attackers trying to fuzz your implementation or use you as DoS amplifier

I also suspect that some really shoddy implementations are based on whatever `string` types their programming language supports and incorrectly handle encoding instead of using arrays of `uint8` as bencoding demands. There's nothing that can be done about those. Ignore or occasionally send an error message.

Specified dictionary keys are *usually* ASCII-mappable, but this is not a requirement. E.g. there are some tracker response types that actually use random binary data as dictionary keys.

---

Here are a few examples of junk I'm seeing<sup>[1]</sup> that even fails bdecoding:

```
d1:ad2:id20:�w)��-��t����=?�������i�&�i!94h�#7U���P�)�x��f��YMlE���p:q9Q�etjy��r7�:t�5�����N��H�|1�S�
d1:e�����������������H# 
d1:ad2:id20:�����:��m�e��2~�����9>inm�_hash20:X�j�D��nY��-������X�6:noseedi1ee1:q9:get_peers1:t2:�=1:v4:LT��1:y1:qe
d1:ad2:id20:�����:��m�e��2~�����9=inl�_hash20:X�j�D��nY���������X�6:noseedi1ee1:q9:get_peers1:t2:�=1:v4:LT��1:y1:qe
d1:ad2:id20:�����:��m�e��2~�����9?ino�_hash20:X�j�D��nY���������X�6:noseedi1ee1:q9:get_peers1:t2:�=1:v4:LT��1:y1:qe
```

<sup>[1]</sup> preserved char count. replaced all non-printable, ASCII-incompatible bytes with the unicode replacement character.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing. In almost all responses I see "ip" key which I didn't find in the bittorrent dht spec but it is used by all nodes. Is there may e a spec amendment in regards to that which is not reflected in the original spec?

Comment: Already said in my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31313281/1362755) that you should read the other BEPs.