# Why I reviced Compact node info in find_node response message is not 26 bytes?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, dht, kademlia

In BEP5 said

> Contact information for nodes is encoded as a 26-byte string. Also known as "Compact node info" the 20-byte Node ID in network byte order has the compact IP-address/port info concatenated to the end.

and

> When a node receives a find_node query, it should respond with a key "nodes" and value of a string containing the compact node info for the target node or the K (8) closest good nodes in its own routing table.

In My find_node response Of java, the Compact node info bytes is not 26 bytes, why?

Comment: partially similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31313281/1362755

Answer (score 1):

The value for the key *nodes* can contain more than one node as indicated by the quote from BEP5:

> ... or the K (8) closest good nodes in its own routing table.

8 * 26  = 208 bytes value length with 8 *Compact node infos* concatenated together.
Many clients even sends the double amount of nodes: 16 * 26 = 416 bytes length.

In practise should a client accept any length that is evenly divisible by 26.